# Black Screen when i try to use Ursina on Python

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *


Entity(model='quad', scale=60, texture='assets/blue_sky')
app = Ursina()

app.run()   # opens a window and starts the game.
```

[when i run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxn4Q.jpg)

[the black screen with nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ciq.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is working but it's just that the scale is too big. Usually if the scale is 15, it covers the whole screen, anything above that would just be the same as 15. Also, you should create entities after Ursina(). So, if you don't want to cover the whole screen, this would be your code (Scale can be anywhere between 1 and 15 but not 15):

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

Entity(model='quad', scale=10, texture='assets/blue_sky')

app.run() # opens a window and starts the game.
```

The above code is working for me but if it doesn't work for you, I don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it actually works. Try with a smaller scale, like 1.
Also, entities should be created after Ursina(), since some things will depend on that.

Comment: it says (3 aux display modules not yet loaded.) everytime.... is it oky tho?

Comment: its still not working